# Bulk items uploaded through Ebay LMS Api not appearing on sandbox store

Tags: php, ebay-api, ebay-lms

I have uploaed xml file compressed by gzip through LMS-php bulkexchange successfully, but items are not showing on sandbox store.

LMS-PHP is asking for only Securtiy Token, but not AppID, DevId & Cert Id.

Store url - http://stores.sandbox.ebay.com/testpww

Response on LMS api

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <getJobStatusResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services">
      <ack>Success</ack>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
      <timestamp>2017-02-24T10:29:18.635Z</timestamp>
      <jobProfile>
        <jobId>50013526730</jobId>
        <jobType>AddFixedPriceItem</jobType>
        <jobStatus>Completed</jobStatus>
        <creationTime>2017-02-24T09:57:09.000Z</creationTime>
        <completionTime>2017-02-24T10:01:11.000Z</completionTime>
        <errorCount>0</errorCount>
        <percentComplete>100.0</percentComplete>
        <fileReferenceId>50013592660</fileReferenceId>
        <inputFileReferenceId>50013592650</inputFileReferenceId>
        <startTime>2017-02-24T09:59:16.000Z</startTime>
      </jobProfile>
    </getJobStatusResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I am novice in using ebay API, its successful message without listing of products troubled me. On further checking, I found that API gives option to download a response file. In this file ebay provides error details. According to which I missed to add xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" in 
     tag.